# pop up of confirmation box when closing tab/window only

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello i need a pop up message of confirmation when going to close browser/tab only, not when going to click on any link. In my code, it gave me pop up message when i close browser/tab as well as click on any link, which i don't want. I really have no idea how to do it. Can anyone please help me. 
My code  is-

```
<body>
    <div id="copyright">
    <div class="moduletable copyright ">


<div class="custom copyright">
    <p>
<span class="copy">© Copyright 2008</span>
 Inc. All rights reserved. </p>
</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
    </div>
        <br class="clear" />
  </div>
</div>
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onbeforeunload = bunload;
function bunload(){
dontleave="Are you sure you want to leave?";
return dontleave;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what you want to do is allow users to navigate through your site without showing the popup, but if they try to "leave" your site (not a page on your site), you want to show the popup?

Comment: Yes, while user navigating through site, they won't get any message, but while closing tab/browser, gives a pop up message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
 <body>
    <a href="demo-1" onclick="prevent()">click here</a>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            return "Are you sure?";
        }
        function prevent() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function () { };
        };

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: it won't work in my website, if i use as above simple code and execute it, it works fine but when updated in my site it won't work as i stated.

Comment: Are you using the same code you've written here? I guess you are missing something there.

Comment: yes am using same code, instead of using    <a href="demo-1" onclick="prevent()">click here</a> , i used my website page code.

Comment: i just gave short code of footer in BODY tag, but in my web page(home page) , contains many links like menu links, img hyperlinks ect.

Comment: If you add the onclick event on anchor tags in your code like me, and follow my code it should work. I'm not getting what's happening in your side, I guess it'll help if I get the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Your said event `onbeforeunload` works perfectly.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

[See it in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/q4pRK/39/)

Comment: functioning of your code is similar to my updated code but i want only when user closing tab/browser not while navigating internal links.

Answer (score 0):

#### Tl/Dr

The below code will be completely pseudo-code describing the method you'll need to run through to get this to work.

---

The first step is that you'll need to add an identifier to all "internal" links within your site. For example, if your page is contact, and there is a link to that page form your home page, you need to distinguish between the types of pages.

```
function confirmExit() {
    if (!internal_link) {
        // random shit..
        return message
    }
}
var key = "internal_link";
window[key] = false;
var message = "Your custom message. Are you sure you want to blah?";
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
internal_link = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!window.location.origin) {
        window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname
    }

    $("a").each(function () {
        if ($(this)[0].href.indexOf(window.location.origin) == 0) {
            if ($(this).attr("onclick") == "undefined") {
                $(this).attr("onclick", key + " = true")
            } else {
                if ($(this).attr("onclick")) {
                    var e = $(this).attr("onclick");
                    $(this).attr("onclick", e + " " + key + " = true")
                } else {
                    $(this).attr("onclick", key + " = true")
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($(this).attr("onclick") !== key + " = true" || $(this).attr("onclick") == "undefined") {
                $(this).attr("onclick", key + " = false")
            }
        }
    });

});
```

The above is what I've used previously and it's worked perfectly. Basically what it does is adds an attribute to internal links (links within your site), then when users navigate around your site, the `onbeforeunload` runs the `confirmExit()` function and checks if the `internal_link` is false, if so, it shows the message otherwise it navigates through the site.

Comment: if i put var internal_link="contact.html" in function confirmExit() and use it in code, still not working.

Comment: how i add 'internal' links??

Comment: No, the script above needs to be included on every page, and it will automatically say "This is an internal link, allow it to navigate"

Comment: but it's very lengthy method,my site having 70pages, acc. to you, on every 70 pages i should add this code....

Answer (score 0):

Nothing work for me but I made it with some combinations of the above code and from other forums.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

        window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            return "Are you sure?";
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('a').click(function () {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            });
            $('form').submit(function () {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The `onbeforeunload` event will be fired when you submit a form too, so we need to prevent the event.